# How to enable right click open new tab option along with the feature of left click that opens in same tab in visual force page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

We have a custome emails section where we can open the email message if we click on the email subject. Below VF code we are using to achieve this.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Subject">
    <a herf="/{!items.id}" 
       style="{!if(items.status == '0','cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;','cursor: pointer;')}" 
       onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" > 
      {!items.Subject} 
    </a>
</apex:column>
```

`onclick` logic written in the java script by using `window.open(pages,'_parent');` with this `onclick` opens the email message in the same tab that is working as expected. But we need to include the right click open new tab option also when we place the mouse over the subject. How to achieve this.

Current Emails section: when mouse over subject and right click. 
[image]

Expected behavior : 
[image]

Comment: Those are [browser context menus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items) and are not controlled by a VF page. As long as your browser displays the context menu on hyperlinks to display the options, it will work on any link. I see you have a typo as `<a herf...>`, if that's the case, you need to have `<a href ...`>

Comment: Thanks Jayant yes it is typo issue. I have updated herf to href and it looks good.

Comment: So are you saying that was the source of the problem? Fixing that now works fine? If yes, you should add that as an answer.